# Can I use Partty (with double "t") instead of Party?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, american-english, vocabulary, names

I am looking for a domain name that ends with Party. However, those names I am looking are already taken. So if I use, lets say , www.WePartty.com (with double 't') instead of www.WeParty.com , would it make a big difference in pronunciation and understanding for English speakers.

English is not my first language and it seems okay for me and others whose second language is English. I don't want my website users to get confused. I want them to see it as if the second 't' doesn't exist.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't the domain read as: www.wepartty.com? To be frank it looks pretty awful; people might read it as *wep artty* and if they do read it as **we partty** they'll think it's a typo. But this is my (very subjective) opinion; others may disagree, and as such I consider your question to be too broad.

Comment: actually I used wePartty as an example .. but its going to be something like www.LetsPartty.com but haven't decided yet. Any comments?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it seems that domain names are written in lower-case letters, this is something you should take into account, capital letters help separate the words but if there are none then it becomes more of a challenge and you might get a completely different meaning. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Domain_name_confusion

Comment: @Mari-LouA Also see `ExpertsExchange.com` and `TherapistFinder.com`.

Comment: Not to mention PowerGenItalia.com,  MoleStationNursery.com and SpeedOfArt.com.

Comment: http://www.partay.com/ is for sale. @SQB Experts-Exchange got their hyphen VERY early in their life

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to consider when picking a domain name is usability.  It has to be easy to remember, logical to the user.  My domain name is www.theeternalscribe.com.  My blog is titled The Eternal Scribe.  When the user thinks of my blog, it is relatively easy to remember the URL.

I think your main concern with using two t's would be the possibility that users might think we party, and forget the second t, resulting in them going to another site -- one not your own.  What's worse, you might be sending your hard earned customers to your competition.

Admittedly, many sites and companies purposefully misspell words.  The spelling should be pervasive throughout the site and all your correspondence.  It should be drilled into your customers.  Easy to remember.

Also try using a thesaurus to come up with variants, other word choices.

You can use "-" to separate words in a domain name as well.

Point being, get creative, and don't be too set on a given option.  Get too set on varying the spelling of a word and you may very well shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are lots of questions here about making up words. We can't help you with your name — that's off-topic — but it's possible to comment on **how** to create one.

If you need a particular word, you need that particular word. You might get away with a misspelling which results in a similar **sound,** like `place4bizness.com`, **provided** that it cannot be misread.

In that example, the different words are distinguished by including a digit *4* for the word *for*, and *business* is deliberately misspelled both to shorten it and perhaps make it more memorable. But *bizness* is pronounced the same as *business*, and it's not similar to any other word; it's not likely to be misread.

When writing such names, you can use capital letters, or differentiate using typeface. For a slightly worse example, placeforbusiness.com, PlaceForBusiness.com and **place***for***business**.com are all valid. Domain names standardise on lower-case letters, but part of the standard is that they are not case-sensitive and capital  letters map on to the corresponding lower-case letter.

Using a double *t* as you suggest **is** likely to be misread, because *partty* is not a word and *parity* is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not asking if you can help me with a naming but asking if the naming I used make sense or not. If it misleads my prospectus (future customers) or not. That way I can make a decision what name to use.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, and I said that explicitly; I've attempted to say how to come up with a name which is better. There's [a question on Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/is-it-fine-to-ask-questions-about-neologism-and-new-words-morphology-here) which is worth a read too. While you're not producing a neologism, you need some of that technique.